# XML Parsing on high volume traffic

Tags: java, multithreading, jaxb, mule

I am parsing xml requests on a high volume traffic. Would JAXB be the fastest way to extract xml?

```
 Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class).createUnmarshaller();
 MyClass myClass = (MyClass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(requestReader);
```

Comment: If you cache the ``JAXBContext``, this is reasonably fast.

Answer (score 3):

Do you **need** to extract the entire xml, or certain subset?

If you are looking to extract a subset of data from xml, Stax/ SAX will likely be more performant than JAXB.
The best way to determine the most performant solution would be benchmark JAXB vs Stax vs SAX.